# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-memory

I keep getting this error when I run my app. The app will compile fine and interaction with the app is normal and until a certain period it will come up with the OUTOFMEMORY error message.

Error Logcat:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:249)
        at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:572)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
        at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:671)
        at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:640)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.<init>(JsonObjectRequest.java:47)
        at com.apps.robotapp.RobotService.onStart(RobotService.java:75)
        at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2833)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

At Java:75 (RobotService:onStart) where the error occurs:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);    
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,SPHERE_URL,obj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //System.out.println("JsonObjectRequest:>>" + response + "<<");
                    System.out.println(response);
                    //hideProgressDialog();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //hideProgressDialog();
                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                }
            }); queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

I have implemented both system.gc() and Runtime.getRuntime().gc() into my implementation, however it still doesn't work.

Any idea how can I tackle this issue? Thanks

Comment: Which line excatly is line 75?

Comment: Invoking the GC is not enough if you still maintain references all around. As an example, I see that you use to call `queue.add` for each object. Do you also take care of popping out elements from that queue or it grows up without control?

Comment: @TDG   This is line 75:`JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,SPHERE_URL,obj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() `

Comment: @skypjack  so what else is needed? I am only roughly familiar with GC method

Comment: You need to release an object so that the GC can free it. See the comment above, I've put there an example.

Comment: @skypjack I don't see any comment from you

Comment: The first one, I've edited it. Comment, not answer.

Comment: @skypjack I don't see your edit

Comment: That one - Invoking the GC is not enough if you still maintain references all around. As an example, I see that you use to call `queue.add` for each object. Do you also take care of popping out elements from that queue or it grows up without control?

Comment: @skypjack that comment!!was a lil confused, sorry about that. `queue.add` is the end of the code, I didn't invoke other elements to take care of the other elements. How should I go about this that will allow me to release for GC to free it

Comment: Do you simply put objects into the queue and you never pop them out? Do you do the same with all of your containers? This is an example of an activity that will lead to the out of memory. A container has a reference to the objects, so the GC will never free them. To help you refactoring your code, we should look at the whole project, but this is not the aim of stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: @skypjack, These are all done in onDestroy() method actually.

Comment: So, you drop the objects calling the onDestroy method, is it? What about if you create ten of them each request and you have tons of requests? The memory consumption goes up and up till an out of memory, as it happens. You are confirming what I'm saying, you use to keep all the objects' references, thus invoking the gc is useless and it is not the solution to your problem. You have to release a bunch of objects if possible, otherwise you'll have the same error sooner or later, no matter how much memory the hosting system has.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the code.
You can follow ref count and RAM consumption :
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Btw. don't you have "Caused by..." in the exception log ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using inordinate amounts of memory, this can happen when you *leak memory*. Leaking is unintentionally keeping references to objects that you do not need anymore.

There are many ways this can happen. The most obvious one is never clearing old items from a cache. In Android you can have [Context related memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), but that may not be the case for you.

Have a look at [Google I/O 2011: Memory Management for Android Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) for a crash course on memory. In the video there's a link to the Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool (MAT) which can help you zoom in on the problem. Mastering this will likely take quite some time, so you may just want to watch the video to get an understanding of memory leaks and then using your common sense and knowledge of your app find the leak by reasoning. Good luck!